# NodeJS authorizationError: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',

Tags: node.js, https

I have tried all possible solution to solve this error **"UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"**. GET request works fine. But POST is not working due to certificate issue,
    Any help to resolve this would be great.
Below is the code snippet

```
function dohttpRequest(requestdata,filename){
    //var localoptions=getOptions(requestdata);
    console.log('entered dohttpRequest');
    console.log(requestdata);
    var localoptions = {
                        //hostname: 'www.tele-servicingafrica.philips.com',
                        //hostname: '192.168.1.205',
                        hostname: '192.168.1.195',
                        key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/sca.key'),
                        cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/sca.crt'),
                        ca:     fs.readFileSync('ssl/sia.crt'),
                        rejectUnauthorized: false,
                        strictssl:false,
                        port: 443,
                        path: '/ATS/ATS.Service1.svc/sftp/UploadFile',    
                        method: "POST",
                        json: true,
                        headers: {
                            "content-type": "application/json",
                            "content-length":requestdata.length
                            },
                        }
    process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
    var req = https.request(localoptions,function(res){
    console.log('entered request');
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    console.log(res);
    console.log(req);
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
            if(res.statusCode=="200"){
                fs.unlink(filename);
                console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
            }       
        });

    });
```

Comment: General security tip: you should never use `rejectUnauthorized: false` or setting the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` environment variable to `0`. Always set the `ca` appropriately to include the server's certificate.

Comment: Ya I agree. these changes are done just to make the code up and running. tried all possible solution. still stuck.

Comment: Are you sure that `ssl/sia.crt` is `192.168.1.195`'s SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes.i'm sure about it.

Comment: Did you try also including in `ca` any or all intermediate certificates in the chain? (You can do this by setting `ca` to an array of Buffers)

Comment: It may also be that the server is missing needed intermediate certificate(s) in its SSL configuration.